# Applying a function to elements of a vector of arrays

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl

I have a list of things which I encoded into a `std::vector<std::array<double,2>>`. This is basically a list of points (x,y). I want to construct another list but now of the points (x,y^2).

I can do this with for loops, but what's the best way to achieve this using the STL algorithms? I was trying to do a `std::for_each` combined with lambdas, but I can't get there yet.

Comment: you should post your not working attempt at doing this.  Otherwise answer is "use std::for_each"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::for_each` applies a function to a range of elements, if you wan to applies a function to a range and stores the result in another range you should use [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform). e.g.

```
std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(), std::back_inserter(dest),
               [](const std::array<double,2>& arr) { return std::array<double,2>{arr[0], arr[1] * arr[1]}; });
```